# Make an apex item red if it is negative

Tags: css, oracle, oracle-apex

I have some display items on the page that I want to show in Red color if their value is negative. The item's value is loaded by some PL/SQL when the page is loaded. The value is a formatted string, e.g. `'-$100.00'`

I can't set the class in the HTML Table Cell Attribute because it is unconditional.

Comment: I've asked and answered this question in case someone has a better idea :)

Answer (score 1):

Use a Dynamic Action to add a class to the item at Page Load:

1. Add a style to the page (e.g. in the Page Header or in a CSS file):

   ```
   <style>
    .negative { color:red }
   </style>
   ```
2. Create a Dynamic Action on the page:

   **Event** = Page Load

   **Condition** = Javascript Expression

   **Value** = `$v("P1_MY_ITEM").charAt(0)=="-"`

   **True Action** = Add Class

   **Fire on Page Load** = False

   **Class** = `negative`

   **Selection Type** = Item(s)

   **Item(s)** = `P1_MY_ITEM`
3. Repeat step #2 for each item that needs this behaviour.

If you want the text color different (e.g. blue) if the amount is not negative, add another class (e.g. `.positive { color:blue }`) to the stylesheet and add a **False Action** to the Dynamic Action.

Also, if the item is editable, the Dynamic Action could be triggered by the **Change** Event instead.

Comment: If it was a report it'd be easier - see e.g. http://tylermuth.wordpress.com/2007/12/01/conditional-column-formatting-in-apex/

Answer (score 0):

What if use this style without DA?

```
<style>
  input[value^="-"] {
    color:red;
  }
</style>
```

This example will not work if item is editable - changing value of item has no effect.

Comment: Hi @NoGotnu, I'm not sure how to get this to work. In my case the items are display items, so they get rendered like `<span id="P6_LYR_ACTUAL_AMOUNT" class="display_only">-$157,931,570</span>`. There are no `<input>` items.

Comment: Hi @Jeffrey Kemp! Unfortunately, there is no content selectors in css. So, only Dynamic action or/and jQuery/javascript. I have only one improvement: if you have many items, don't create DA for each ITEM. Add to all your item's some class, smth like "cash", then create one DA, having code: `$('.cash:contains("-")').addClass('negative');`